# Spark : Applying map function on Dataset<T> in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have below code which works fine with `foreach` function on Dataset.`finalJoined` is a `DataFrame`.

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    ClassTag<KieBase> classTagTest =  scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(KieBase.class);
    Broadcast<KieBase> broadcastRules = context.broadcast(kContainer.getKieBase("rules"), classTagTest);


    Encoder<RuleParams> encoder = Encoders.bean(RuleParams.class);
        Dataset<RuleParams> ds = new Dataset<RuleParams>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);
        System.out.println("Printing ruleParams DS");
        ds.show();
        ds.foreach(ruleParam -> droolprocess(broadcastRules.value(), ruleParam));
```

Here `foreach` method returns **void**.

I need `Dataset<RuleParams>` as return value . below is my **droolprocess** method which calls rule engine and updates **RuleParams** objects.

```
public static void droolprocess(KieBase base, RuleParams ruleParams) {
        StatelessKieSession session = base.newStatelessKieSession();
session.execute(CommandFactory.newInsert(ruleParams));
        System.out.println("After firing  rules");
        System.out.println(ruleParams.getPriceItemParam1());
        System.out.println(ruleParams.getCisDivision());
         }
```

I have seen some questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere but I am not sure how to write `map` function instead of `foreach`  to return `Dataset<RuleParams>`

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below:

```
 Dataset<RuleParams> ds = new Dataset<RuleParams>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);
    StructType schema = ds.schema();
    ds = ds.map(ruleParams -> {

RuleParams theRuleParams= ruleParams;

    ...//your processing
    return theRuleParams;
    }, RowEncoder.apply(schema));
```

Once mapping is done you need to return row by creating each of the row if you adding/deleting and modifying data in each row.
Finally apply back the schema so that the dataset knows the schema that it will be returning after performing the `map` operation.

Comment: In above code do you mean I need to replace Object by RuleParams?

Comment: Or i need to replace row with ruleParams?

Comment: As I require ruleParams object inside for processing.

Comment: Also i am passing broadcast variable KieBase base which is a broadcast variable in side foreach how can i pass same inside map?

Comment: Yes you can replace Object with RuleParams because your row is a sequence of RuleParams.

Comment: `Seq<RuleParams> seq = row.toSeq();
List<RuleParams> seqAsJavaList = new ArrayList<>(JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq));` is just an example, you can do any operation on `row` and finally just return a row of RuleParams

Comment: Okay, but as you can see my droolsprocess functions works on ruleParam objects and not on row, then how this row can be useful? also how to base variable as i am doing in droolsprocess?

Comment: Dont get confused with the words. May be i can say row is nothing but your RuleParams. You will get all the RuleParams one by one as a row. I have changed the names, hope that make sense